# Why does not work properly 'na_values' in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading [this file](http://www.sidc.be/silso/INFO/sndtotcsv.php) and replacing `-1` with `nan`:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = "./data/"

filename = os.path.join(path,"SN_d_tot_V2.0.csv")    
names = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'dec_year', 'sn_value' , 'sn_error', 'obs_num']
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=';',header=None,names=names,na_values=['-1'], index_col=False)
```

But replacement works only for `sn_error` column which is `float64`, and does not for `sn_value` which is `int64`. What is wrong? How to replace all `-1` values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column has leading spaces, you will need to strip them out while reading your CSV.

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.sidc.be/silso/INFO/sndtotcsv.php', 
                 sep=r'\s*;\s*', 
                 engine='python', 
                 header=None, 
                 names=names,
                 na_values=[-1], 
                 index_col=False)
df.head()

   year  month  day  dec_year  sn_value  sn_error  obs_num
0  1818      1    1  1818.001       NaN       NaN        0
1  1818      1    2  1818.004       NaN       NaN        0
2  1818      1    3  1818.007       NaN       NaN        0
3  1818      1    4  1818.010       NaN       NaN        0
4  1818      1    5  1818.012       NaN       NaN        0
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain a bit how it works, all 2 columns `sn_error` and `sn_value` have spaces. Why does replacement work for `float` and does not for `int` without deleting spaces?

Comment: @dereks It seems like some cells have spaces while others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Use converter parameter

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=';',header=None,names=names,converters={'sn_value':float,'sn_error':float}, na_values=['-1'], index_col=False)
```